# InnoDB field type size vs file size descrepency?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I created these tables:

```
create table aca (money TINYINT);
create table acb (money SMALLINT);
create table acc (money INT);
create table acd (money BIGINT);
```

I ran the following inserts over and over to add 9420 rows:

```
INSERT INTO aca (money) VALUES(7), (8), (9), (10), (12);
INSERT INTO acb (money) VALUES(7), (8), (9), (10), (12);
INSERT INTO acc (money) VALUES(7), (8), (9), (10), (12);
INSERT INTO acd (money) VALUES(7), (8), (9), (10), (12);
```

When I check the files on the server it shows each database being slightly larger than the other:

```
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 360448 Jul  5 14:21 aca.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 376832 Jul  5 14:21 acb.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 393216 Jul  5 14:21 acc.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 442368 Jul  5 14:21 acd.ibd
```

Since each field is twice as large as the next, I would expect each database file to be roughly twice the size (given a small difference because of headers), but this is not the case and instead of being double the size (100% larger) they are 4-13% larger.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What goes into an InnoDB table?  Here's a rough list:

- Since you have not `PRIMARY KEY`, a hidden 6-byte number is added.
- Each column is preceded by a length and null info.  This may add 2 bytes per row in your case.
- There is all sorts of overhead for each row, including transaction stuff, etc.  One estimate is 29 bytes per row.
- A BTree is filled to no more than 15/16th full.  (15KB / 16KB).

Meanwhile, a handy Rule of Thumb for typical table definitions is to multiply the obvious total column size by between 2 and 3 to get the size of the .ibd file.  This does not work for your case because you have an unrealistically small number (1) of columns.

Looking at just the basic, constant, overhead:

```
9420 * 16/15 * (29+6) = 351KB
```

That number fits nicely as a lower bound on the table sizes you got.

Another issue:  At some point, InnoDB grabs chunks of space ("extents") of 4/8/16MB (I'm not sure of which size it is).  I guess you have not hit that yet.  When that happens, the computations get even more confusing and hard to follow.

Suffice it to say, InnoDB has made some tradeoffs.  They 'waste' some space (sometimes a lot of space) to make the processing simpler and faster.

If you had had a `PRIMARY KEY` then the 15/16 comes into question.  If you insert in PK order, then the 15/16 sticks.  But if you insert randomly, it drops to about 69%.  This is because of block splits.

Oh, and "large" text/blob columns go "off-record".  And the `ROW_FORMAT` adds wrinkles.

And, if you did this with MyISAM, you would be given puzzling sizes like 75360, 75360, 75360, and 94200.  Those are much simpler to explain, and, if I got them right, very predictable.

Confused enough yet?